# How to pass music Service from one Activity to another

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I'm starting my Music Service in my Main Activity where I display a list of songs. On clicking a song, it takes me to another activity where I do the basic controls. How do I continue with this same service in my second class?

Main Activity:

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var musicSrv: MusicService? = null
private var playIntent: Intent? = null
private var musicBound = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = Intent(this, MusicService::class.java)
        bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        startService(playIntent)
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    stopService(playIntent)
    musicSrv = null
    super.onDestroy()
}

fun songPicked(view: View) {
    musicSrv!!.setSong(view.tag.toString().toInt())
    musicSrv!!.playSong()
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SmartPlayerActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("title", songList[view.tag.toString().toInt()].title)
    intent.putExtra("artist", songList[view.tag.toString().toInt()].artist)
    intent.putExtra("duration", songList[view.tag.toString().toInt()].seconds)
    startActivity(intent)
}

private val musicConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        val binder = service as MusicBinder
        musicSrv = binder.service
        musicSrv!!.setList(songList)
        musicBound = true
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
        musicBound = false
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Will fragments be suitable for your use case?

Comment: Maybe this will help: create a new class maybe called ```MusicServiceInstance```, and put ```musicConnection: ServiceConnection```  in it, then make it ```public static```. So every activity can access ```musicConnection```.